# How can I join 3 tables (or sub-select) in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table called `searches` which has an `id` and a table of `positive` and `negative` which are associated with a `search_id` and has a `word` (ie: "some positive word" or "some negative word".

I'm trying to do this all in one query (not sure if its possible): I want to get a list of searches where the search does not contain any of the negative words in the list and DOES include any of the positive words in the list.

The basic idea is given a search id (i'm trying to find related searches)...get this search ids positve and negative words, and then select all other searches where their positive words match (any one or more words) and does NOT match any of the negative words.

```
    const positive = await db.queryEntries(
      `SELECT * FROM positive WHERE search_id = ?`,
      [search_id]
    );
    const negative = await db.queryEntries(
      `SELECT * FROM negative WHERE search_id = ?`,
      [search_id]
    );
    console.log("positive: ", positive, " negative: ", negative);
    let pIn = "";
    let nIn = "";
    positive.forEach((p, i) => {
      pIn += "?" + (i < positive.length - 1 ? "," : "");
    });

    negative.forEach((n, i) => {
      nIn += "?" + (i < negative.length - 1 ? "," : "");
    });
    console.log("pIn", pIn);
    const pWords = <[]>positive.map((p) => p.word);
    const nWords = <[]>negative.map((n) => n.word);
    console.log("pWords", pWords);
    const args = [].concat(pWords, nWords);
    console.log("args", args);
    /*
           INNER JOIN positive pos ON pos.search_id = s.id
       INNER JOIN negative neg ON neg.search_id = s.id

       */
    const searches = await db.queryEntries(
      `SELECT s.* FROM searches s, positive p, negative n
      INNER JOIN positive ON s.id = positive.search_id
      INNER JOIN negative ON s.id = negative.search_id
       WHERE p.word IN (${pIn}) AND p.word NOT IN (${nIn})
       `,
      args
    );

    console.log("searches: ", searches.length);
```

I've tried so many things now and I keep getting thousands of rows and there should be only 3 searches that match

Here are some queries:

```
sqlite> .schema positive
CREATE TABLE positive (
                                id string PRIMARY KEY,
                                search_id STRING NOT NULL,
                                word string NOT NULL);
sqlite> select * from positive where word = 'css';
a63303ca-7b07-49d8-a500-fa3e48c6657d|e428da2f-334d-4444-8b78-719480393112|css
32da7a93-8aea-493a-bd55-e99eacc40d92|621882c3-db65-47a4-bd0d-fc39ed09aabe|css
f805c86f-9436-40d8-8b26-0639bdb8d06d|3779ba1b-9b42-43d1-9133-e5622176ce83|css
sqlite> select * from positive where word = 'css';
a63303ca-7b07-49d8-a500-fa3e48c6657d|e428da2f-334d-4444-8b78-719480393112|css
32da7a93-8aea-493a-bd55-e99eacc40d92|621882c3-db65-47a4-bd0d-fc39ed09aabe|css
f805c86f-9436-40d8-8b26-0639bdb8d06d|3779ba1b-9b42-43d1-9133-e5622176ce83|css
sqlite> select * from negative where word = 'css';
sqlite> select * from searches LIMIT 1;
326f3d15-97cd-4da9-bd82-a1578ac8e15f|1535d3e5-cb05-4514-81c8-4fa787e52e53|svelte|2021-11-01T08:10:10.982Z|2022-02-20T03:10:42.128Z|job
sqlite> 
sqlite> .schema searches
CREATE TABLE searches (
                                id STRING PRIMARY KEY,
                                user_id STRING NOT NULL,
                                name STRING NOT NULL,
                                created_at TEXT,
                                updated_at TEXT
                        , type TEXT DEFAULT 'job');
```

so for example if the requested search has 'css' as a positive word and 'angular' as a negative word, I want all searches that have css as a positive word and DO NOT have angular as a postitive word.

Comment: What is your expected output from this query? I see in your code that you select n.word which does not make sense.

Comment: Still it's unclear what your expected output is. Post sample data and your expected output to clarify.

Comment: I need to get a list of searches that match the criteria

Comment: I have posted the schemas

Comment: so for exazmple if the request search has 'css' as a positive word and 'angular' as a negative word, I want all searches that have css as a positive word and DO NOT have angular as a postiive word.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` to check if the words exist or not in the 2 tables:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM searches s
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM positive p WHERE p.word IN ('css', ... ) AND p.search_id = s.id)
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELCT 1 FROM negative n WHERE n.word IN ('angular', ... ) AND n.search_id = s.id);
```

Comment: can you explain what the `SELECT 1` in the subquery is doing?

Comment: also how would I join this on the users table so I can get a user object in addition to search? Would be something like users.id = s.user_id

Comment: @chovy `1` is just a dummy column returned by the query. It could be `0` or `null` or `*`.

Comment: @chovy `SELECT s.*, u.* FROM searches s INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = s.user_id WHERE ...`